# How to get students data from Moodle into LTI tool ( Web application )

Tags: node.js, request, moodle, lti

I am building a web application as an LTI tool. How do I request the students' data(grades, courses) from the Moodle LMS into my web application ( built using Node.js )?

I have used this documentation to understand how to send grades back to LMS. However, I cannot find any resource which explains how to receive students' data from moodle and display it into my LTI web application. ( https://cvmcosta.me/ltijs/#/?id=table-of-contents )

Answer (score 0):

If you are using LTI1.1 you should look at the LTI Basic Outcomes Service

http://www.imsglobal.org/specs/ltiv1p1/implementation-guide#toc-27

If you are using LTI1.3Advantage you should look at the Assignments and Grades Service

https://www.imsglobal.org/spec/lti-ags/v2p0